# Robocopy moving files from one source to multiple destinations , only if files are not empty

Tags: robocopy

I am trying to move files from single source to multiple destination folders . Below is the command that is working perfectly.

`robocopy C:\source C:\destination`
`robocopy C:\source C:\destination1 /MOV`

After moving to Destination1, Files are deleting from the source directory. It is working fine. But I am trying to move only files which are not empty .

Below are the commands that I am using
`robocopy C:\source C:\destination  /MN:1`
`robocopy C:\source C:\destination1 /MOV /MN:1` `

I am getting this error on cmd.
`ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : "/MN:1"`
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found issue. There was a wrong command `MN:1`. Below is the correct one.

```
Echo off
robocopy C:\src C:\dest1 /min:1
robocopy C:\src C:\dest2 /MOV /min:1
```

`robocopy C:\src C:\dest1 /min:1`  This line copies not empty files from source to destination.
`robocopy C:\src C:\dest2 /MOV /min:1` This line moves not empty files from source to destination.